# Assert statement to compare two files for equality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, assert

I am writing from one file to another and i created an Assert statement in my tests to check and see if the new file equals the original file but was not sure what is the best way to go about it. I tried `Assert.Equals` but it returned as failed even though i physically checked both files and they are exactly the same.

```
 Assert.IsTrue(File.Equals(downloadfile, created), "Files do not match");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an MD5 or SHA hash of the files, and compare those.

```
public string GetFileHash(string filename)
{
    var hash = new SHA1Managed();
    var clearBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    var hashedBytes = hash.ComputeHash(clearBytes);
    return ConvertBytesToHex(hashedBytes);
}

public string ConvertBytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(var i=0; i<bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

[Test]
public void CompareTwoFiles()
{
    const string originalFile = @"path_to_file";
    const string copiedFile = @"path_to_file";

    var originalHash = GetFileHash(originalFile);
    var copiedHash = GetFileHash(copiedFile);

    Assert.AreEqual(copiedHash, originalHash);
}
```

Comment: Your hex conversion should always use 2 chars

Answer (score 5):

I refactored the answer of ia.solano and created FileAssert class

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace Test.Helpers
{
    public static class FileAssert
    {
        static string GetFileHash(string filename)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists(filename));

            using (var hash = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                var clearBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
                var hashedBytes = hash.ComputeHash(clearBytes);
                return ConvertBytesToHex(hashedBytes);
            }
        }

        static string ConvertBytesToHex(byte[] bytes)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static void AreEqual(string filename1, string filename2)
        {
            string hash1 = GetFileHash(filename1);
            string hash2 = GetFileHash(filename2);

            Assert.AreEqual(hash1, hash2);
        }
    }
}
```

And usage in test is following:

```
using Test.Helpers;

[Test]
public void CompareTwoFiles()
{   
    FileAssert.AreEqual(@"path_to_file1", @"path_to_file2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7931353/2551839

this answer shows how to compare files, use that function on your assert